# How Send a audio via web service(HTTP-PUT) with php from Android

Tags: php, web-services, http, mp3, put

I need to transfer via web service with php
an mp3 file so that it can receive compressed and the app can unzip
but I really have no idea how you can do
receive compressed and then unzip

Comment: Why do you need it compressed? mp3 files are already "compressed".

Comment: sorry, I was not clear, it really is not necessary to compress
transferiar file but i know how to URL
but in this case I was told that it did not apply
which was requested via HTTP PUT

Comment: Sorry, so what is the question exactly?